ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE when serving a React app on Nginx from Docker image
I have a React app that I created with Vite. I want to dockerize and deploy it to several environments, and serve it on Nginx. From Docker image, I want to run it locally via docker-compose, for other environments, which are on kubernetes, like staging and production, I will use helm charts.
Also I will use Vite to serve the app locally to test my changes immediately.
I need to pass different environment variables for different environments for the same docker image, because the image will be created once on release step of my pipeline and then will be pulled and used commonly for dockerized setups (local Docker via docker-compose and Kubernetes setup).
I have found a solution to pass environment variables after docker image is created. I am appending the variables to window object and running the script from my index.html before starting anything. I have templated this object and filling it via envsubst.
Locally, via Vite, I am able to run the application. However, this does not work on Docker. I am getting ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE..
I have checked the nginx.config and other files if exists in my docker image in the expected directories and yes, they are, and the env. vars also seem filled correctly. However, I couldn't figure out what is going wrong.
I will share the files needed below (kubernetes setup I can figure out later, so I don't share:
# Dockerfile

# Use alpine base image for building
FROM alpine:3 AS builder

# Install necessary packages
RUN apk update && \
    apk upgrade && \
    apk add --no-cache bash git openssh tini yarn npm

# Set working directory and copy the project to the container
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

# Install dependencies and build the application
RUN yarn install
RUN yarn build

# Use the standard nginx image for serving
FROM nginx:alpine

# Install gettext for envsubst (for environment variable substitution)
RUN apk add --no-cache gettext

# Create necessary directories
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/nginx /var/run /var/www/html

# Copy the nginx configuration template
COPY ./nginx/nginx.conf.template /etc/nginx/templates/nginx.conf.template

# Set the working directory for serving the application
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Copy built files to the served directory
COPY --from=builder /app/dist/ /var/www/html

# Copy the runtime environment template for envsubst
COPY ./nginx/runtime-env.js.template /usr/share/nginx/html/runtime-env.js.template

# Copy the entrypoint script
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chown -R nginx:nginx /entrypoint.sh

# Set ownership of files to nginx user
RUN chown -R nginx:nginx /var/www/html

# Use the entrypoint script
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]


# entrypoint.sh

#!/bin/sh
# Replace environment variables in the template
envsubst < /usr/share/nginx/html/runtime-env.js.template > /usr/share/nginx/html/runtime-env.js

# Start Nginx
nginx -g 'daemon off;'


# runtime-env.js.template

window.__RUNTIME_CONFIG__ = {
  VITE_BACKEND_BASE_URL: "${VITE_BACKEND_BASE_URL}",
  VITE_AUTH_SERVER_URL: "${VITE_AUTH_SERVER_URL}",
  VITE_REALM: "${VITE_REALM}",
  VITE_CLIENT_ID: "${VITE_CLIENT_ID}"
};

# nginx.conf.template

server {
    listen 8080;

    # Set headers for security policies
    add_header 'Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy' 'require-corp';
    add_header 'Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy' 'same-origin';

    # Serve files from the root directory
    root /var/www/html;

    # Upstream api requests
    location /api/ {
      rewrite ^/api/(.*)$ /$1 break;

      proxy_pass http://${UPSTREAM_HOST}:${UPSTREAM_PORT};

      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    }

    # Default location for all non-api requests
    location / {
        alias /var/www/html/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}

# extract from docker-compose.yaml
...
  acme-frontend:
    image: acme-frontend
    depends_on:
      - acme-backend
    environment:
      - VITE_BACKEND_BASE_URL=http://localhost:8110 # acme-backend is running on here and confirming it's up and running
      - VITE_AUTH_SERVER_URL=https://host.docker.internal:9443/auth
      - VITE_REALM=SuperUsers
      - VITE_CLIENT_ID=superuser-service-public
      - UPSTREAM_HOST=pass-backend.acme.local
      - UPSTREAM_PORT=8080
    ports:
      - '8111:8080'
    container_name: acme-frontend.acme.local
  ...

# index.html

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vite + React + TS</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/runtime-env.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.tsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>

